# Do I use the plural or singular form of a noun when saying "zero or one"?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

E.g. Do I say "I have zero or one child" or "I have zero or one children"?

Comment: Strictly speaking, number agreement goes with the closest word, in the same way as the verb does. In your sentence, it would be: *I have zero or* ***one*** *child.* If you reversed the words, it would be: *I have one or* ***zero*** *children.* However, neither version sounds good. I would rephrase it. (1) *I have less than two children.* (2) *I have either no children or one child.* (3) *I have one child or none at all.* (4) *If I have any children at all, it's just one.* Or simply: *I have zero children or I have one child.*

Comment: Nobody would ever say _I have zero or one child/children_, no matter what the suffix was. _Zero_ is the name for a symbol, not a negative morpheme except metaphorically. If one doesn't know how many children one has, but is certain that there's no more than one, one could say _I have at most one child_; but that is an extremely remote context, for which no language has built-in constructions.

Comment: Oh my bad I should have given the actual context. I actually wanted to say "Percentage of families with zero or one child."